# Write vector $\vec{u}$ as a sum of vector parallel to $\vec{v}$ and perpendicular to $\vec{v}$

Tags: calculus, vectors

Write vector $\vec{u}$ as a sum of vector parallel to $\vec{v}$ and perpendicular to $\vec{v}$

$\vec{u}$ = $< 2,4,2 >$ and $\vec{v}$ = $< 1,2,-1 >$

I was pretty sure that the way to solve it was to find the parallel vector by doing

$
  u_1
= \left(\frac{|u|\cdot |v|}{|v| \cdot |v|}\right)v $

and then subtract that vector from $\vec{u}$ to get the perpendicular one.

That left me with $\vec{u}$ = $< 2,4,-2 > + < 0,0,4 >$ which can't be correct because the second vector isn't perpendicular to $\vec{v}$.

What am I doing wrong, or did I mess up my algebra?

Comment: Look up Gram-Schmidt orthogonalization.

Comment: Your original formula is just wrong. You do not multiply the magnitudes of $u$ and $v$, or else you'd just get $|u|\dfrac v{|v|}$, which is nonsensical.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard way is\begin{align}\vec u&=\left\langle\vec u,\frac{\vec v}{\left\|\vec v\right\|}\right\rangle\frac{\vec v}{\left\|\vec v\right\|}+\left(\vec u-\left\langle\vec u,\frac{\vec v}{\left\|\vec v\right\|}\right\rangle\frac{\vec v}{\left\|\vec v\right\|}\right)\\&=\left(\frac{4}{3},\frac{8}{3},-\frac{4}{3}\right)+\left(\frac{2}{3},\frac{4}{3},\frac{10}{3}\right).\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

You want that

$$(\vec{u}-\lambda \vec{v})•\vec{v}=0$$

or

$$((2,4,2)-\lambda (1,2,-1))•(1,2,-1)=0$$

So,

$$(2-\lambda)+2(4-2\lambda)-(2+\lambda)=0$$

thus

$$\lambda=\frac 43$$
and

$$\vec{u}=\lambda \vec{v}+ (\vec{u}-\lambda \vec{v})$$

Answer (score 0):

You must have done some calculation mistake. By your formula the parallel vector is
$$v_{//}=\frac{(2,4,2)\cdot (1,2,-1)}{1^2+2^2+(-1)^2}(1,2,-1)=\frac{4}{3}(1,2,-1)$$
Then
$$v_{\perp}=u-v_{//}=\left(\frac{2}{3},\frac{4}{3},\frac{10}{3}\right)$$

And indeed $v_{\perp}\cdot v_{//}=\dfrac{4}{9}(2+8-10)=0$